# getting IndexError: list index out of range after execution

Tags: python, list, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

added text code, sorry for the inconvenience, i just wanted to include the terminal output in my post.

edit2: removed all images, here is my latest code + input / output in text format, i found the error in the input file but i couldn't fix it with code, there is a completely empty row at the end of the file when i manually edit the file and back space to remove it the code works fine, is there is anyway to solve this issue is my csv files are automatically generated by airodump and i don't know if i can control their formatting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import csv

#def nonblank_lines(f):
#   for l in f:
#       line = l.rstrip()
#       if line:
#           yield line

with open('root-01.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
with open('station_value.csv', 'w') as station_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(station_file, delimiter = ',')
    for skip in range(4):
        next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)

with open('station_value.csv', 'r') as csv_file2:
#   for line in nonblank_lines(csv_file2):
csv_reader2 = csv.reader(csv_file2)
with open('pwr_value.csv', 'w') as pwr_file:
    csv_writer2 = csv.writer(pwr_file, delimiter = ',')
    for line in csv_reader2:
        try:    
            print(line)     
            csv_writer2.writerow([line[3]])
        except Exception as details:
            print('Invalid data:',line,'rejected due to',details)
```

here is my input file in text format:

## root-01.csv

```
BSSID, First time seen, Last time seen, channel, Speed, Privacy, Cipher, Authentication, Power, # beacons, # IV, LAN IP, ID-length, ESSID, Key

1C:5F:2B:0A:02:58, 2017-12-02 04:01:06, 2017-12-02 04:02:34,  6,  54, WPA2, CCMP TKIP,PSK, -85,      654,      155,   0.  0.  0.  0,   6, Halbos, 



Station MAC, First time seen, Last time seen, Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs

40:40:A7:67:90:0E, 2017-12-02 04:01:16, 2017-12-02 04:02:33,  -1,       63, 1C:5F:2B:0A:02:58,

80:3F:5D:F9:1F:AB, 2017-12-02 04:01:22, 2017-12-02 04:02:09,   0,      557, 1C:5F:2B:0A:02:58,
```

## station_value.csv

```
Station MAC, First time seen, Last time seen, Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs

40:40:A7:67:90:0E, 2017-12-02 04:01:16, 2017-12-02 04:02:33,  -1,       63, 1C:5F:2B:0A:02:58,

80:3F:5D:F9:1F:AB, 2017-12-02 04:01:22, 2017-12-02 04:02:09,   0,      557, 1C:5F:2B:0A:02:58,
```

## pwr_value.csv

```
 Power

  -1

   0
```

getting station_value.csv is working fine, the issue arises (As far as i understand) when i want to get the value of line[3] from statio_value.csv and write it to a new file pwr_value.csv because there is an extra line at the end of station file that doesn't have the same size as the previous lines. i tried to get the stack trace but wasn't able to as the debugging tool just keeps showing blank white space whenever i open the stack trace.

I also don't understand why does still produce the pwr_value file even though there is an error?

Comment: Post your code as text, not as picture!

Comment: BTW, if you get an exception it can't be a "successful execution" by definition

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: "how to go about debugging this?" <- add print(line) before print(line[3]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to make some assumptions here because you didn't post the stack trace, and you didn't post a sample data file. But the only place you could have that error is line 9, and the only reason you would get that is because you are expecting the csv file to have 4 columns, and one line of the file (at a guess, the last one) does not. I suspect you have a trailing blank line at the end of your input file, but it might be duff data in the middle. A `print` statement (as timgeb suggests) would be good, but you could also put a permanent validation trap in your code, for example,

```
for line in csv_reader:
    try:
        print(line[3])
    except Exception as details:
        print('Invalid data:',line,'rejected due to',details)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have included the csv file in the post, it was there initially but i removed it because it also had the code which apparently was not allowed, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: That is not the input, it is a picture of the input. The reason pictures of your code are not allowed is that we cannot run them. And a picture of the input isn't any use for the same reason. Your program is expecting ascii data, not a picture. As I indicated, the problem you report is almost certainly in the data and not in the code. Post your input as code, your output as code, and report the entire error message you get including the stack trace. Otherwise it's not possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You were absolutely correct with your guess "and the only reason you would get that is because you are expecting the csv file to have 4 columns, and one line of the file (at a guess, the last one) does not." i edited my input file manually and the code worked, but is there is a way to do it such as the last line is ignored or not taken into consideration (maybe dropped from the end of list)?

Comment: Well, yes. If you want to ignore the blank line, then check each line to see if it is blank before assuming it isn't. The `try...except` clause does that, but if you know the line will be blank and don't want an error message, then change the code so it does not assume that `line[3]` exists. For example, `if len(line) < 3: continue`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort,i was able to solve the error and marked your answer as solution, your patience in pointing out the errors in my way of asking questions is most impressive, once again thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the tickmark and best of luck.